# Video card and ram issue

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card

One month ago, I decided to fix and upgrade my pc, for example, change ram and add a video card.

I order a MSI GeForce 1050Ti Gaming X 4gb, I installed it and there were no problems. Problems started when new RAM arrived.

Before changing them, there where 4gb (2x2gb) by Corsair; I replaced them with Kingston HyperX Fury 2x4gb and I switch on the pc. When it started, it was loading windows, it stopped and restarted; then it started loading windows, it stopped and restarted again.

I tried to use 1 hyperX and 1 corsair and it worked. Then I tried 2 hyperX without video card and it worked. I thought it was a power problem, but it restarts only when I try to use windows.

What could be the problem? How do I fix it?

> Motherboard: Asus p7h55-m lx
>
> GPU: MSI GeForce 1050Ti GamingX
>
> CPU: intel core i3-540
>
> New ram: Kingstone hyperX Fury 2x4gb
>
> Old ram: Corsair 2x2gb (CMV4GX3M2A1333C9)
>
> Storage: seagate barracuda st1000dm003

Comment: Go into BIOS before you allow Windows to run. BIOS (Basic Input Output System), will initialize the system BIOS so it can be used. Also, find your computer's USER book(s), even if you have to download a PDF file. There maybe a certain way to load the RAM in sets. https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8H61_M_LX/U5307_P7H55-M_LE_LX.zip?_ga=2.176729314.650671405.1585814963-899611558.1585814963

Comment: The best way I find to add to a Windows system, put your graphics back in and allow BIOS to find the device, boot Windows to install your software for that, don't remove it once it is installed. Restart then Shut down the system. Add the system RAM, the boot in to the system BIOS, to initialize the RAM, restart the machine from BIOS and reboot to Windows.